# Multiple joins in Pentaho

Tags: left-join, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I am trying to join 5 flows in which the first one is the driver and the others are being left outer joined to driver. I have used Ab Initio in the past where we could use a single join component and specify the kind of join for each input flow. I couldn't find any such Step in the Pentaho and hence I have to rely on the Merge Join which left outer joins only two tables at a time and then take its result to join with the next and so on and so forth. I am planning to do all that in a single transformation.
What I am worried about it since Pentaho runs all the Steps in parallel, it might start to run a join which is much later in the flow without waiting for an earlier join to complete. Is this a valid concern? if so how do you tackle it in a single transformation?

Answer (score 1):

That’s correct you can only join 2 steps at a time.
Answer to your second point, no it will execute parallel but your second join will wait for your first joie to finish. So you will get a proper result only.

Comment: I confirm. PDI is data driven. It means you do not know in which order PDI will open the database connection, but it will not process data before it is needed. That is in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks. But if one join waits for the previous one then what happened for the following user: https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/83324-Multiple-table-inputs-with-merge-joins-in-one-transformation/                                                  
This is the exact situation that I am trying to avoid